# How do I stop Google from providing me language localized search results?

Tags: google-search, localization

For several webpages, Google provides me with language localized search results.

For example, I search for *bread* and I get as a result:

```
www.cooking.example/bread/de
```

which is the German localized version of what I was actually looking for:

```
www.cooking.example/bread
```

How do I teach Google that I'm capable of understanding English and actually prefer the English version of most websites?

Comment: you need to make changes in settings on google homepage, however you need to be logged in for your settings to be remembered (if cookies aren't saving it, like for me on safari on mac os x mojave beta

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, I think. If anyone else knows of other/better ways please post.

Under *Search Settings*, which at the time of writing this can be accessed through the cog at the top right of a search results page, there is also a section for *Languages*.

Checking all languages you can understand for the *"Currently showing search results in"* setting isn't actually enough and didn't actually change anything for me.

Apparently, you have to set Google (*"Which language should Google products use?"*) itself to the language you primarily want to receive search results in, which has the side effect of Google itself also being in that language.